# How to invoke a siebel web service from a PHP web application?

Tags: php, web-services, siebel

I am developing a Portal in which i have to pull some data from a siebel Call center application through one of the published web services. I would be glad if some body provides some code snippet for a sample application.

Answer (score 1):

All web services from siebel are published with SOAP protocol, you only need to get the wsdl from siebel client application > web services > Inbound. Use it from php with php_soap client, for example. Here is an example about writting a soap client in php: [php_soap client](http://devzone.zend.com/article/689)

I have samples in java, python and perl of siebel webservices invokations but, not for php. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is even possible.  Most of the Siebel business layer access is only doable via OLE or Java object interface.  Maybe if access was exposed using an Integration service of sort you could do it, like maybe MQ or something.

I short, I have no example.  It would need to be cobbled together.  If you figure it out, Ravi, you will be paid much money.  Good luck, my friend!